# How to use files with multiple extensions with Prettier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint, package.json, prettier

I have following [**Prettier**](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) commands:

```
prettier --parser typescript --write ./src/**/*.ts
prettier --parser typescript --write ./src/**/*.tsx
```

I would like to **merge them to single one** - use some king of regex to listen (write) on both `.ts` and also `.tsx` extensions.

Something like:

```
prettier --write ./src/**/*.ts(x?)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Just found solution. Following command will target both **ts** and **tsx**:

```
prettier --write "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
```

[Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) is using **[Glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md) syntax** which is syntax similar to Regex, used in shell.

See GLOB syntax details: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md#glob-primer

Comment: Are you sure it's not your shell expanding that glob pattern?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe without `" "` will be used shell directly ? https://github.com/prettier/prettier#cli But I am on windows, so not sure..
Please if you can provide better explanation would be appreciated and I may accept your answer. Or just do edit..

Comment: Ah, in Windows it might work differently. Anyway, it's not really relevant as it's working :D

Comment: Yea it is working now, but always is good to know explanation why.. and if it's expanded by shell - not glob lib, it's pretty much difference - even if it's done only on Unix-like system..

Comment: You can try and put quotes around it. If it still works, it's `prettier` that does the expansion. On Unix, you can also try `echo ./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}` to see how the shell expands it, perhaps that works on Windows too.

Comment: I think the answer should be amended to surround with quotes for 'nix platforms.

Comment: @khoomeister Yep, that's true, let's use Prettier glob instead of relying on system. Updated answer.

Comment: How can I do this using a config file? @Jurosh

Comment: @lomse as far as I know - no, this needs to be in command line.

Comment: True. I figured it out later. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use `{ts,tsx}` in prettierrc config file?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to run prettier command on multiple paths with multiple extensions use the following command:

```sh
prettier --write "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}" "pages/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}" "server/**/*.js"
```

Comment: It can be simplified as `"prettier --write \"{src,pages,server}/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}\""`